# Do we use " at " or " in " with part of the day?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

This kinda confused me when we were learning about **Prepositions** ..

Because sometimes I hear  *at night*. and another time I hear **in the evening**

even though both of them are part of the day

Comment: This is a complex matter and you really need a grammar book on the subject. It comes up a lot on the site, so it may well be worth doing some search activity here.

Comment: Prepositions are particularly idiomatic. They do not always make perfect sense just because they are established. Traveling, I learned that I would be _in_ France but _inside_ Paris. If _inside_ makes more sense than _in_ (other than being idiomatic), then what do we do _in_ New York City? Both languages are entitled to their idioms.

Comment: Just as a general guideline, English tends to use _at_ for specific times of day or night (at dawn, at sunset, at noon, at midnight) and with parts of day that generally don't take a definite article (at night); but it tends to use _in_ with parts of the day that do generally take a definite article (in the morning, in the afternoon, in the evening, in the wee wee hours). But this guideline isn't as clear-cut as one might wish, because English accepts both "at night" and "in the night" as idiomatic forms.

Answer (score 1):

It likely has to do with specificity. "At night" implies at the time of nightfall, whereas "in the night" could be any time during which it is dark. "In the evening" is rather subjective as there is no agreed upon evening hour. Likewise, one would say "at five o'clock" for greater specificity but "in the five o'clock hour" for a generalized time.

Comment: Generally agree with you, but I don't think **at night** infers time of nightfall at all. **At night** could mean _any time_ of night. (EXAMPLES—Q: When do you like to see movies? A: Usually at night. Q: Are you meeting them at 11:30 in the morning? A: No, 11:30 at night.)